# Bootstrap-Datepicker not working in Ruby App

Tags: jquery, ruby, datepicker

When trying to use bootstrap-datepicker-rails in my Ruby app, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

The JS/Coffeescript code i'm using is:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

My application.js file contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_self
```

I get the same error if i enter the following command in the console:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

The code in my form looks like:

```
<%= f.text_field :date, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', class: 'datepicker' %>
```

How can i get datepicker to work?

Comment: check the path of bootstrap-datepicker js

Comment: Bootstrap-datepicker seems to be loading fine, the code is all there, in the source it points to:
/assets/bootstrap-datepicker/core.js?body=1

Comment: Also what is the point of bootstrap-datepicker-rails. Just copy bootstrap-datepicker.js into vendor/assets/javascripts.

Comment: @davidfurber - downloading it and placing it in the assets folder manually did the trick. it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per davidfurber's suggestion, copying bootstrap-datepicker.js into vendor/assets/javascripts fixed the issue